# How to find the candidate key by having a set of functional dependencies?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

Consider relation R = (A, B, C, D, E, F) and a set of functional dependencies:

```
AB --> C

BC --> A

BC --> D

D -->  E

CF --> B
```

What are all the candidate keys?

Please if anyone can give me the answer and explain how.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/ueberdeckung.php?fds=+A+B+-%3E+C%2C+B+C+-%3E+A%2C+B+C+-%3E+D%2C+D+-%3E++E%2C+C+F+-%3E+B&language=en) for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how to find candidate keys in a simple manner:

Form a three columns,left,right and middle

> In left column,add the attributes which appear only on left hand side of FD
>
> In right column,add attributes which appear only on right hand side of FD
>
> In middle column,add attributes which appear both on right and left hand side of FD

Explanation:

> Attributes on left column indicates,every possible candidate keys must include these attributes

and

> Attributes on right column indicates candidate keys should not include it

and

> Attributes on middle may or may not be included in super keys

In the given example,F is placed in left column and A,B,C,D are placed in right column and E is placed in right column

Then,apply Closure property,

> AF+->AF **reflexivity rule**
>
> BF+->BF **reflexivity rule**
>
> CF+->ABCDEF

because

> CF->CF **reflexivity rule**
>
> CF->B **given**
>
> CB->A **given**
>
> CB->D **given**
>
> CB->A **transitivity rule** CB->D and D->A

Thus,CF->ABCDEF and **CF** is the **candidate key**

Hope,this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I hope [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1DNVWKeQ_w) will help you finding the candidate key for this answer .

As per my analysis candidate key for these functional dependencies are :

AB, BC, ABC, ABD, BCD, ABCD

Comment: I don't think ABCD is a superkey, it must be the minimal set of keys, ABCD is not minimal

Comment: Any attribute that doesn't appear on the right-hand side of any functional dependency must appear in every candidate key. That means every candidate key must contain the attribute "F". *None* of your candidate keys contain the attribute "F".